# Changing active Git user through CLI

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, command-line-interface

*I was introduced mid-ways in a project, in which have a web server set up running Ubuntu that uses version control through Git, connected to a repository on organization A. Now, this project's source code needs to be moved to organization B on Git, and thus it has been created and the files have been transferred on my local computer.*

So, I guess all I need to do now, is to change the active Git user on the server (through CLI) to one that has access to the correct repository in organization B, and point to that particular one. Trying to figure out which user is currently active, I performed

```
$ git config -l
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
```

Which leaves me a bit blank. How is that related to the current repository?

Answer (score 0):

`git config user.name` will tell you the user.

You'll find the user settings in the `.gitconfig` file

Comment: 'git config' contains nothing else than listed above. There is no user name listed. I will look in .gitconfig when I get home though.